# What does "Fur Reichbeshaffenungsamp" (embossed on a camera) mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english

Embossed on a camera are the words

> Fur Reichbeshaffenungsamp

I have tried to split the letters but cannot find a true meaning.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Do take a [tour] of the site and visit our [help] if you have any remaining questions. I have the feeling that you got some letters wrong there. Are you sure that the spelling you gave is correct? Could you maybe prove it by a picture?

Comment: _Für Reichsbeschaffungsamt_, I assume. If spelt differently, it is guaranteed to be fake. :-)

Comment: As @chirlu wrote, this is most certaInly a fake. fwiw, `Reichsbeschaffungsamt` has been the Procurement Office of the Miltary in Imperial Germany through the Third Reich

Comment: @collapsar: Well, unless it was made in China or so at the time of war. But then, why would they order cameras in the far east when they had their own good camera manufacturers (i.e. Leitz)?

Comment: @PMF The engravings on the camera body might have been added on behalf of the Allied post-war occupation forces in Germany. Note the different coloring wrt to the manufacturer's data [in this pic from an auction site](http://user21823.vs.easily.co.uk/large/cm010715/lot0903-1.jpg). Still somewhat dubious.

Comment: Thank you for replying . Leica camera's are often faked so quite likely that this camera is also fake.

Comment: Wie alt soll die Kamera denn ungefähr sein? Das Leica-Logo wurde kaum vor 1990 verwendet. Und die Markennamen Leitz und Leica auf dem selben Produkt erscheinen auch etwas seltsam (Leitz ging in Leica auf).

Answer (score 4):

If there really is embossed

> Fur Reichbeshaffenungsamp

then you've got a cheap imitate, because there are 5 errors in it. In correct German it would be:

> Für Reichsbeschaffungsamt

The errors are:

1. The **u** in *Fur* is wrong. It must be **ü** (*Umlaut-u*) (*Für*).
2. There must be an **s** after *Reich* (a so-called *Fugen-s* that has the function of an connector between the elements of a compound noun.)
3. There is an **c** missing in what should be the German trigraph *sch* (*sh* is English, not German)
4. The Verb is *beschaffen* (to obtain, to procure), but the noun, that is derivates from it, is not build by just adding the suffix *ung*. It is built by replacing the previous suffix *en* with it. So *Beschaff**en**ung* is wrong, correct is *Beschaffung*.
5. The last letter can't be a *p*, because there is no German word *Amp*. It is *Amt* (*office, authority, department*)

But even with the imprint »Für Reichsbeschaffungsamt« I would be sceptic, because omitting the article is grammatically wrong. I only can imagine this if the space where it is embossed is limited.

If there had been many different Reichsbeschaffungsämter then it should be »Für **ein** Reichsbeschaffungsamt« (*for **an** Empire-Procurement-Department*). But there was just only one Reichsbeschaffungsamt. So it should be:

> Für das Reichsbeschaffungsamt

And this is in english:

> **For the Empires Department for Procurement**
>
> für = for
>   das = the
>   Reich (a neuter noun) = empire<sup>1</sup>
>   beschaffen (a verb) = to obtain, to procure
>   Beschaffung (a female noun) = procurement
>   Amt (a neuter noun) = office, department, authority

<sup>1</sup> A note about »*Reich*«:
When talking about the historic european nation »Deutsches Reich« that existed between 1933 and 1945, the German word »Reich« often is left untranslated in english texts. So:

> ger: Deutsches Reich = eng: Deutsches Reich
>   ger: Drittes Reich = eng: Third Reich
>   **but:**
>   ger: Römisches Reich = eng: Roman Empire